# Promiseオブジェクトのfinallyメソッドを実行するとエラーが出るのはなぜでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

いつもお世話になっています。
【質問の主旨】で示すJavaScriptコード（promise.js）について質問です。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

```
function runAsync(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (typeof value === 'number') {
        resolve(value * 2);
      } else {
        reject(new Error(`${value}は数値ではありません。`));
      }
    }, 500);
  });
}

runAsync(15)
  .then(response => console.log(`成功［${response}］`))
  .catch(error => console.log(`失敗［${error}］`))
  .finally(() => console.log('終了'));
```

このファイルを実行すると2秒後にrunAsync関数の引数になっている数字が、2倍に変化してコンソール画面に表示されるコードです。

```
.finally(() => console.log('終了'));
          ^
TypeError: runAsync(...).then(...).catch(...).finally is not a function
```

`node promise.js`でターミナルから実行すると上記のエラーが表示されます。なぜでしょうか？

#### 【質問の補足】

```
runAsync(15)
  .then(response => console.log(`成功［${response}］`))
  .catch(error => console.log(`失敗［${error}］`));
```

上記の通りメソッド2つに減らすと、`成功［30]`とだけ表示されます

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

node.jsのバージョンが古いと思われます。

Promiseのfinallyは比較的新しいメソッドなので、古い環境では使用できません（[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally#Browser_compatibility)）。

node.jsで使用するには、**node.jsのv10以上**が必要です。

Comment: Faily Feely さん。
コメントありがとうございます。

>node.jsで使用するには、node.jsのv10以上が必要です。

ご指摘に通り、node.jsのバージョンを10以上にすると`finnaly`メソッドが使えるようになりましt。

```
$ node -v
v10.15.1
$ node promise.js

成功［30］
終了
```

アドバイス助かります。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。